# How to send an asp control to javascript

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I am trying to send an asp control (textbox) to a javascript function.

```
onblur="CalculateLossRatio(this.value,<%=txtLossRatioCurrentYear.ClientID%>)"
```

Is is the right way to do this.

Comment: Is txtLossRatioCurrentYear a different Textbox than the one the onblur event is fired from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you could do something like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onblur="CalculateLossRatio(this.value, 1)" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="7"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

function CalculateLossRatio(arg1, arg2)
{
    if (arg2 == 1)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>');
    }
    else if(arg2 == 2)
    {
        // TODO - get other txt...
    }

    alert(arg1 - txt.value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I want to send other textbox too. So I would not be able to use (this).

Comment: @vaibhav: I think you'd better go with var txtbox = document.getElementById("txtLossRatioCurrentYear"); for the second textbox...

Comment: But I need to generalize this function. I want to send different textbox to javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

thats is acceptable, what you are actually doing there is using a preprocessor directive

`<%=txtLossRatioCurrentYear.ClientID%>` will be substitute on runtime by the generated ID of the control, passing `this.value` will pass the reference of the control but you can still obtain it using the `var txtbox =  document.getElementById(controlid);`

Answer (score 0):

You can send the reference to the sender directly to your js-function(its not clear from question if there is another Textbox):

```
onblur="CalculateLossRatio(this)"

function CalculateLossRatio(txtBox)
{
    if(txtBox != null){
       var text=txtBox.value;
    }
}
```